# Electron DevTools Inspector not showing on Linux

Tags: electron, fedora, devtools

I am running an electron app on Fedora Linux machine, and while the main Electron app is rendering fine, right-clicking and choose "Inspect Element" doesn't bring up the DevTools window.

I also tried "View" -> "Toggle Developer Tools" menu, but the window isn't brought up either.

I don't think this is an issue with the app, because DevTools work for this app on Mac/ other platforms.

Is there something I need to do in order for the devtools windows to show up?

Comment: Did you try opening it on start with `win.webContents.openDevTools()`? or the `CTRL + SHIFT + I` shortcut.

Comment: Yes I've also tried both of those.

Comment: Did you check if the dev tools window opened and might just be out of bounds?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by out of bounds. But I don't see any new window at all on the computer.

Comment: I mean it's open but the window is outside your view of the monitor.

Comment: I don't think so - I don't any any indication of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239221/discussion-between-tri-nguyen-and-crimson589).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem is that I'm using a older electron version (11.x). Upgrading to a new version (anything from 13.5.0 onwards) fixes the issue.

It came down to this bug https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/31047, though I'm still not sure why this only affected my Fedora environment and not others.

Answer (score 1):

Run the AppImage with --no-sandbox. It should work.